# How to add checkbox with multiple values in table?

Tags: database, settings-api, wp-list-table

Right now i changed from `options` table to my own table so things are getting difficult

i have a checkbox its name is `selection` in table, so here is what i tried

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="1"<?php checked("1",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="2"<?php checked("2",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="3"<?php checked("3",$item['selection']);?> />
```

This is not saving any value , Then i tried as array in below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="1"<?php checked("1",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="2"<?php checked("2",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="3"<?php checked("3",$item['selection']);?> />
```

It is throwing warning `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

How to store multiple values with the same name in checkbox when using my table ?

Any help help would be greatful.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress function [checked()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) just compares two given values and - if the comparison is true - adds the checked attribute to a radio button or checkbox. The second parameter is default **true** so you can use the PHP function [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array) if you have to check if a given value is in an array like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="1" <?php checked( in_array( '1', $item['selection'] ) ); ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="2" <?php checked( in_array( '2', $item['selection'] ) ); ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="3" <?php checked( in_array( '3', $item['selection'] ) ); ?> />
```

I assume that you [saved your data serialized](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) and that you [unserialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) them before you use them like in the example.

When you submit the form you can get and serialize the value of the field for saving it into the db like this

```
$str = maybe_serialize( $_POST['selection'] );
```

When you then get it from the database you should unserialize the value

```
$item['selection'] = maybe_unserialize( $str );
```

This is important because just in this way you can restore the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1 for in_array. am not sure about data serialize is [maybe_serialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) fine for that?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect for that.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't figure out that. I tried like `<?php $serialized_sel = maybe_serialize('selection'); ?>` and used this in the name field like `name="<?php echo $serialized_sel; "?>` any help please

Comment: `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given`

Comment: OK I will add an example what I mend with the serialization-part.

Comment: i have done serialization `$serialized_sel = maybe_serialize('selection[]');` like this and included this in the process meta `$item = shortcode_atts($default,$serialized_sel, $_REQUEST);`. This is fine it is not getting any warning as shown in question.

Comment: Now am getting `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given` now i have to unserialize it.

Comment: I tried `$unserialize = maybe_unserialize($item['selection[]']);` and icluded in `<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="1" <?php checked( in_array( '1', $unserialize ) ); ?> />` but no use.

Comment: Do i have to change the field name in create table to `selection[]`

Comment: I added a part with the an explanation of serialize/unserialize. The POST-var is 'selection' BTW.

Comment: Thanks but we have this brace `[]` is that fine without mention them in the `maybe_serialize`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11300/discussion-between-realloc-and-sun)